# OWIN/Katana: Authentication Middleware

Tags: authentication, cookies, oauth, signalr, owin

I'm almost driving crazy looking for the right way to implement appropriate authentication functionality for my OWIN/Katana project using SignalR.

I already read about writing an own OAuth2.0 Service, I heard about using cookie authentication, and using SignalR's [Authorize] attribute. Yet, I am not quite sure about whether any of these approaches meet my requirements.

I have the following scenario:
I've got a host application that performs a WebApp.Start() for let's say TWO owin hosts.
Each owin host has various middlewares.

What I want to do: At the beginning of each OWIN pipeline I want to add an OWIN middleware that presents a login-page and allows the user to authenticate. If the user has been successfully authenticated, he is able to reach any other middlware in the pipeline. If the user browses to a further pipeline before authenticating, he should be redirected to the login page.

The problem: I found plenty of articles describing how to write an OAuth 2.0 server and so on. What I did NOT found is a step-by-step tutorial showing how to authenticate using JavaScript and after that, share and use the authentication data in each middleware that has to check if the user is authenticated.

Does anyone have a good tutorial of how to achieve something like this?
Or, is it even possible to share the authentication data between multiple OWIN IAppBuilder instances. (Each middleware is a separated DLL, in my case.)

Please don't blame me for not reading any documentation or something, I really did already spend a looot of time investigating in how to approach something like this. IMHO there is no really good article describing how to achieve something like that.

Or, at least, can anyone explain to me how to work something out?

Thanks in advance!

Ronald

Project structure: https://pl.vc/2y86u

Answer (score 0):

I have a project OWIN.Framework that allows you to have multiple OWIN pipeline segments with routing. This would allow you to have some middleware that runs first, and multiple pipelines behind this configured with different middleware in each pipeline.